# Audio on VMware vSphere server

Tags: audio, virtual-machine, virtualization, vmware, vsphere

I have a virtual machine which is hosted on VMware vSphere server. 
VMware vSphere server does not have a physical sound card so it's unable to add virtual sound card to the VM.

Is there a way to add virtual sound card to the VM even though VMware vSphere server does not have a physical sound card?

Comment: What is the reason you will need sound card on virtual machine?

Comment: i am implementing a watson virtual agent in my java application. Which i will be deploying on VM. This Agent will make a web socket connection from VM to another rest Api.

Answer (score 0):

You should not need a physical sound card on the server to add a virtual sound card to a VM.  VMware Workstation can add virtual sound cards to VMs hosted on ESX (note that remote sound is not supported, however, so it might not do you any good).

Perhaps another thing to try would be to get a USB sound "card" and connect it as a client-side USB device with the remote console. (I don't know offhand how well that works.)